# Why can't there be fructification of mycelium in submerged culture?

Tags: mycology, sex, fermentation

I am very new at this. I am wondering why fed batch cultures produce a lot of mycelia but no fruit. I thought the more mycelia you had, the greater chance of it forming a fruit body.

I am refering to this paper http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3768415/ but there are many others with the same methodology. It seems to oppose fruit  body production to submerged cultures.

It seems to be submerged in water and in sugar.

It also seems you can have fruit bodies with a single mating type :
- Coprinus sterquilinus (The Fungi by Sharma)
- A bisporus and V volvacea (Chang Chiu)

Comment: Can you provide some more background to your question? What species are you working with, for what purpose, and exactly what do you mean with "submerged culture" (grown in water?)? In general, fungi produce fruit bodies (Sporocarps) after hapliod hyphae of different mating types have fused, and environmental conditions are also important. If your culture only  includes one mating type/batch culture, this could be a reason why you do not see any fruit bodies.

Comment: Do you have a reference on what those environmental conditions are ?

Comment: Can be all sorts of things, and depends completely on the species. Note that many species produce fruit bodies during a particular time of the year (in seasonal environments), which can give you some clue. Can you back up your last statement (fruit body from a single mating type)?

Comment: I think it's a paper by Ohta but let me check

Comment: Great. It might occur, but should be an exception from what I know. Sex in fungi is complicated though, and not my area at all.